CAA VS2008 don't have the "New CAA V5 Workspace"option in file
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/JfjMUGa2.png)
enter image description here
I had tried to install the VS2008 with SP1 and caa,catia again and again, but I didn't see any change of the VS2008. I also had updated the SDK and JDK for the windows 10.

Which version of CATIA are you using? The version or versions of VS you need depend on the version of CATIA.   R31 for example no longer requires the VS2012 and VS2008 parallel installs but instead only needs VS 2017 for everything.

My CATIA version is V5R21.
